# Apache2 proxypass does NOT work for POST request

Tags: apache, proxy

I'm using Apache2 to route incoming requests to backend python flask web service and Splunk web service, there are running on the same server. I need to use POST to upload my file.

Here's my apache proxy setup:

ProxyPass /api/ http://10.68.57.166:5000/api/
ProxyPass / http://10.68.57.166:8000/

The test shows POST request has not been successfully routed, GET request is working fine although, the message says the method is not allowed, because my python flask only allows POST and OPTIONS.

Please help give me some thoughts of how to get it fixed ? very appreciated.

```
Gent79 tmp $ curl -v -X POST http://10.68.57.166/api/upload
 Trying 10.68.57.166...
Connected to 10.68.57.166 (10.68.57.166) port 80 (#0)
> POST /api/upload HTTP/1.1
> Host: 10.68.57.166
> User-Agent: curl/7.45.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 400 BAD REQUEST
< Date: Fri, 15 Jul 2016 02:28:28 GMT
< Server: Werkzeug/0.9.6 Python/2.7.9
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 192
< Connection: close
< 
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.</p>
* Closing connection 0
Gent79 tmp $ curl -v -X GET http://10.68.57.166/api/upload
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, GET is already inferred.
*   Trying 10.68.57.166...
* Connected to 10.68.57.166 (10.68.57.166) port 80 (#0)
> GET /api/upload HTTP/1.1
> Host: 10.68.57.166
> User-Agent: curl/7.45.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 405 METHOD NOT ALLOWED
< Date: Fri, 15 Jul 2016 02:28:41 GMT
< Server: Werkzeug/0.9.6 Python/2.7.9
< Content-Type: text/html
< Allow: POST, OPTIONS
< Content-Length: 178
< 
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>405 Method Not Allowed</title>
<h1>Method Not Allowed</h1>
<p>The method is not allowed for the requested URL.</p>
* Connection #0 to host 10.68.57.166 left intact*
```

Comment: Are you sure that `400 Bad Request` is not actually coming from backend api?

Comment: I think the server field : Werkzeug/0.9.6 Python/2.7.9 can tell us it's coming from backend python script.